# Use of break statement

Tags: java

This program generates output `13 15 x=6` and according to me this should not be the output. The value of `x` stops increasing after 6. Once the value of `y` gets greater then 14 it breaks out of the if statement, but we did not break out of the for so according to me for loop should continue incrementing the value of `y`. It should increment the value of `x` up to 7 and print it.

```
class Output {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Output o = new Output();
        o.go();
    }

    void go() {
        int y = 7;
        for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {
            y++;
            if (x > 4) {
                System.out.print(++y + " ");
            }
            if (y > 14) {
                System.out.println("x=" + x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (a) Format the code properly, your IDE has a "format" option. It's hard to read this code. (b) Explain what your code is supposed to do, and then explain the problem. Please [edit] your question and correct those issues.

Comment: y=7;x=1;y=8;x=2;y=9;x=3;y=10;x=4;y=11;x=5;y=12;y=13;x=6;y=14;y=15 -- perfectly fine. Watch your y++ vs ++y.

Comment: Add a break point and step through your code, then you will see whats hapening

Comment: Why do you believe you need the `break`? If you think you need it to 'break out' of the if-statement why isn't there one in the first if-statement?

Answer (score 3):

The `break` and `continue` statements in almost ALL programming languages is only used to manipulate loop control. When you say that you "break out of the if statement," well that isn't possible.

In you program, once `y > 14` that `break` statement is going to end the entire for statement regardless of its condition, and the function too.

Since you said you're a beginner I'll leave the fixing to you, consider what I just said.